# Почему выводит в таком виде?

Tags: c++, база-данных, структуры

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>;
using namespace std;

struct NOTE
{
    string name;
    int TELE;
    int BDAY[3];
};

int main()
{
    const int size = 3;
    NOTE BLOCKNOTE[size];
    int i, j;
    int n = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << "Vvedite name" << endl;
        cin >> BLOCKNOTE[n].name;
        cout << "Vvedite tele" << endl;
        cin >> BLOCKNOTE[n].TELE;
        cout << "Bday" << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        cin >> BLOCKNOTE[n].BDAY[3];
        cout << "Name " << BLOCKNOTE[n].name << endl;
        cout << "TELE " << BLOCKNOTE[n].TELE << endl;
        cout << "Bday" << BLOCKNOTE[n].BDAY << endl;    
    };
    system("pause");
    return 0;
};
```

Comment: А в каком должно выводить?

Answer (score 2):

Потому что это массив `int BDAY[3];`, который низводится до простого указателя на `int`, каковой указатель и выводится - по умолчанию как шестнадцатеричное значение.

Вы должны выводить как

```
cout << BLOCKNOTE[n].BDAY[0] << "." << BLOCKNOTE[n].BDAY[1] << "." << BLOCKNOTE[n].BDAY[2];
```

А вводить нужно **все три** числа в разные места: не

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    cin >> BLOCKNOTE[n].BDAY[3]
```

(еще и с выходом за границу массива!), а

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    cin >> BLOCKNOTE[n].BDAY[i]
```

Если вы, конечно, об этом выводе, а не, например, имени - в вопросе вы же не указали, **что именно** вас беспокоит...

Вот исправленный код: https://ideone.com/YrtPBD

Comment: Да вы верно поняли что именно меня беспокоит, но при таком выводе который указали вы происходит следующее.   Vvedite name
anton
Vvedite tele
12345
Bday
30
11
1997
Name anton
TELE 12345
BDay 2.06588e-3161.93474e-3141.97626e-322
Vvedite name

Comment: Vvedite name
anton
Vvedite tele
1997
Bday
30
11
97
Name anton
TELE 1997
BDay 080
Vvedite name      То было при double это при int

Comment: Не вижу в вашем исходнике, который вы дали, ни одного `double`.